# How can I prove $(0,2]$ is a smooth manifold? And something questions about the choice of the open set of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I am studying manifold, when I see the definition about the topological manifold, I am confused about the choice about the open set. For example, when we study the real line $\mathbb{R}$ we usually choose $(a,b)$ to be the open set we consider, but when it comes to the form $(a,b]$, we have to choose $(c,b] \subset (a,b]$ to be the open set to cover the $(a,b]$ (am I right?). But if we want to show that $(a,b]$ is a smooth manifold, we have to find the chart. So how can I find the proper homeomorphism which makes the open set of $(a,b]$ is homeomorphic to the open subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: A half-open interval is not a manifold but a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I met a problem today. This problem wants me to show $\mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ is a manifold, and $\mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ is just $(0,2\pi]$ (am I right?)

Comment: As a set you could say yes but an interval can be disconnected by removing one point and the circle cannot, so there is a topological difference

Comment: @R.Sherlock: No, you are wrong.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Why am I wrong? $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is not $(0,2\pi]$?Or $\{[x] : x\in (0,2\pi]\}$?

Comment: You have to use the quotient topology.

Comment: @MoisheCohen does the open set of $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is like (a,b]. And I can prove that $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is Hausdorff and second countable then it suffices to show that it is locally Euclidean.

Comment: I suggest, you review the concept of quotient topology (which you can find in any general topology textbook). Also, avoid using the terminology "is like" since it has no mathematical meaning.

Comment: As a set, $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z \ne (0,2\pi]$, it is instead the set $\left.\Big\{\{x + 2k\pi \mid k \in \Bbb Z\}\right| x\in \Bbb R\Big\}$. Topologically, $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ is also not homeomorphic to $(0,2\pi]$. Instead it is homeomorphic to the circle.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks a lot! I know what's going on. Since this quotient map is a open map, and the preimage of the open set of $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is open of $\mathbb{R}$ the this quotient map is continuous, so I just have to prove this map is smooth?

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks, I get that

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that $M= (0, 2]$ is a topological manifold of dimension $1$ with boundary.

Here is an interior chart. Define $\phi : (0, 2) \subseteq M \to \mathbb{R}^1$ by $\phi(x) = x$, then $((0, 2), \phi)$ is an interior chart since $\phi$ is clearly a homeomorphism. So every point $p \in (0, 2) \subseteq M$ is contained in a neighborhood of $M$ homeomorphic to an open susbet of $\mathbb{R}^1$ and so all such $p$ are (manifold) interior points of $M$.

Now here is a boundary chart, define $\psi : (1, 2] \subseteq M \to \mathbb{H}^1 = [0, \infty)$ by $\psi(x)= -x+2$, then $\operatorname{Im}(\psi) = [0, 1)$ which is open in $\mathbb{H}^1$ and $\psi$ is clearly a homeomorphism. Thus $\{2\}$ is contained in a neighborhood of $M$ homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^1$ and so $2$ is a (manifold) boundary point of $M$.

Thus $M$ is a topological manifold of dimension $1$ with boundary.